# Heroku Deployment Error - Requiring ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, activerecord, deployment

This is my first time trying to deploy a backend Rails app to Heroku, and I'm finding a problem with ActiveRecord. The strange thing is that ActiveRecord is not being used in my application at all. It's not in my Gemfile, and I am not using a database. When I deploy to Heroku, however, I see this message in my logs:

````
2017-05-29T21:07:47.824117+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rails server`
2017-05-29T21:07:52.180887+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:176:in `rescue in spec': Specified 'sqlite3' for database adapter, but the gem is not loaded. Add `gem 'sqlite3'` to your Gemfile (and ensure its version is at the minimum required by ActiveRecord). (Gem::LoadError)```

This leads to a long list of errors and warnings about ActiveRecord, culminating in `2017-05-29T21:10:40.107538+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed`

followed by `2017-05-29T21:10:40.089176+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1`.

After this first failure, the subsequent logs all read:

```2017-05-29T21:10:39.968550+00:00 app[web.1]:     from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:85:in `tap'
2017-05-29T21:10:39.968551+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:85:in `server'
2017-05-29T21:10:39.968551+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:49:in `run_command!'
2017-05-29T21:10:39.968552+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
2017-05-29T21:10:39.968553+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:9:in `require'
2017-05-29T21:10:39.968553+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:9:in `<main>'
2017-05-29T21:10:39.983313+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting Puma
2017-05-29T21:10:39.983318+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 5.0.2 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:11396
2017-05-29T21:10:39.983319+00:00 app[web.1]: => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
2017-05-29T21:10:39.983320+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2017-05-29T21:10:40.089176+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
````

I cannot install the `sqlite3` gem, however, since it's not supported on Heroku. Does anyone know how to remove the requirement for ActiveRecord, or whether it's something else causing this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `gem 'sqlite3'` with `gem 'pg'` in your Gemfile. Although you may not require a database, Heroku ships with one on the rails stack. Rails itself is packaged with ActiveRecord even though you do not use it.

Replacing sqlite3 with pg should get you past this.

Comment: Thanks, this worked! I also had to change the database.yml file to account for postgresql